# Barebone Linux Bluetooth pairing

Tags: command-line, bluetooth, bluez

I have a small embedded ARM box, without any KVM, just a serial console, Net and a Bluetooth USB dongle.

System is autocompiled using Buildroot framework and reasonably working.

I can access the box either via serial line or via ssh.

I have the bluetooth stack running and I can see hci0:

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 00:15:83:3D:0A:57  ACL MTU: 310:10  SCO MTU: 64:8
        UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN AUTH
        RX bytes:7576 acl:27 sco:0 events:267 errors:0
        TX bytes:1396 acl:27 sco:0 commands:130 errors:0
```

I can scan and also "be visible" from outside.

I need to pair with my Android phone and I found out its address, but I didn't find any way to process authentication.

```
# hcitool scan
Scanning ...
        A0:F8:95:54:C8:00       Wiko MCondarelli
# rfcomm connect hci0 A0:F8:95:54:C8:00 1
Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Operation now in progress
```

results in the following trace:

```
< HCI Command: Inquiry (0x01|0x0001) plen 5
    lap 0x9e8b33 len 8 num 0
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Inquiry (0x01|0x0001) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Inquiry Result with RSSI (0x22) plen 15
    bdaddr A0:F8:95:54:C8:00 mode 1 clkoffset 0x6d1c class 0x5a020c rssi -77
> HCI Event: Inquiry Result with RSSI (0x22) plen 15
    bdaddr A0:F8:95:54:C8:00 mode 1 clkoffset 0x6d1c class 0x5a020c rssi -77
> HCI Event: Inquiry Result with RSSI (0x22) plen 15
    bdaddr A0:F8:95:54:C8:00 mode 1 clkoffset 0x6d1c class 0x5a020c rssi -76
> HCI Event: Inquiry Complete (0x01) plen 1
    status 0x00
< HCI Command: Remote Name Request (0x01|0x0019) plen 10
    bdaddr A0:F8:95:54:C8:00 mode 1 clkoffset 0x6d1c (valid)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Remote Name Request (0x01|0x0019) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Remote Name Req Complete (0x07) plen 255
    status 0x00 bdaddr A0:F8:95:54:C8:00 name 'Wiko MCondarelli '
< HCI Command: Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) plen 13
    bdaddr A0:F8:95:54:C8:00 ptype 0xcc18 rswitch 0x01 clkoffset 0x6d1c (valid)
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Create Connection (0x01|0x0005) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Link Key Request (0x17) plen 6
    bdaddr A0:F8:95:54:C8:00
> HCI Event: Connect Complete (0x03) plen 11
    status 0x10 handle 42 bdaddr A0:F8:95:54:C8:00 type ACL encrypt 0x00
    Error: Connection Accept Timeout Exceeded
```

I am bound to "legacy" pairing because:

```
# hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1
Can't set Simple Pairing mode on hci0: Input/output error (5)
```

The trace for the above command is:

```
< HCI Command: Write Simple Pairing Mode (0x03|0x0056) plen 1
    mode 0x01
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Write Simple Pairing Mode (0x03|0x0056) status 0x01 ncmd 1
    Error: Unknown HCI Command
```

which I understand means "Secure Simple Pairing" is not supported by my hardware.
On my system I have BlueZ v3.57, but I do not have hcid, bluetooth-agent, passkey-agent or bluez-simple-agent.

How can I pair using just the basic tools?
If that is not possible: what is the bare minimum I need to install to my box?